# Do not clip bounds of AndroidView in Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

From `AndroidView` [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/viewinterop/package-summary#androidview):

> `AndroidView` will clip its content to the layout bounds, as being clipped is a common assumption made by `View`s - keeping clipping disabled might lead to unexpected drawing behavior. Note this deviates from Compose's practice of keeping clipping opt-in, disabled by default.

This seems to suggest that there is a way to turn clipping off, but I can't manage to do so.

I've tried:

- `Modifier.graphicsLayer(clip = false)` on the `AndroidView`
- `clipToPadding = false` on the `View`
- `clipToOutline = false` on the `View`
- `clipChildren = false` on the `View`

Is it possible to turn off clipping?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a known [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/186313536), here's a workaround until it's implemented:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun <T : View> AndroidView(
    clipToBounds: Boolean,
    factory: (Context) -> T,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    update: (T) -> Unit = NoOpUpdate,
) {
    androidx.compose.ui.viewinterop.AndroidView(
        factory = factory,
        modifier = modifier,
        update = if (clipToBounds) {
            update
        } else {
            {
                (it.parent as? ViewGroup)?.clipChildren = false
                update(it)
            }
        }
    )
}
```